# MEF Event Aggregation without unity/prism (any builtin class in .net 4)

Tags: wpf, events, .net-4.0, mef, aggregation

Does MEF has Event Aggregation like feature builtin (I don't want Prism etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't have this built in.  If you don't want to use something like Prism you would need to create your own contracts for event aggregation, I think.